# MVC looping through model in aspx equivalent to repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to mimic a repeater in MVC aspx page, as follows : But find the opening and closing brackets gets very annoying after a while and realized I must be doing something wrong.

Is this the wrong way to go about it, the syntax just feels wrong ?

```
<% if (Model != null)
   {
       %>
           <table>
       <%
       foreach (var item in Model)
       {%>

       <%} 
       %> 
            </table>
       <%
   }
%>
```

and I my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmployeePerformanceSummary(FormCollection fc)
    {
        var fromDate = fc["fromDate"];
        var toDate = fc["toDate"];

        var param1 = new SqlParameter("@fromDate", fromDate);
        var param2 = new SqlParameter("@toDate", toDate);

        var model = _db.Database.SqlQuery<EmployeeSummary>(
            "employeesummary @fromDate, @toDate ", param1, param2).ToList<EmployeeSummary>();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: That's why many developers prefer Razor view engine.

Comment: Gotcha, I am working on a existing project which uses aspx so want to keep some consistency. So the above foreach looping is the way to do it then ?

Comment: Looks fine. Personally I would change the formatting to separate code and markup, but that's just a preference. Any real trouble you have with this?

Comment: Not really it was just after doing <% %> for the 5 or 6th time, I was just thinking this isn't right

Comment: @StevieB, then advice is to keep C# code in as little lines as possible, like this: `<% if (Model != null) { %>` - all in one line. VS will fight and try to autoformat it differently, but we found markup is a bit more readable that way. Again, just an advice

Comment: @StevieB yes it's the right way. WebForms the syntax "is not modern" itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is correct, but as Andrei commented above, most people would format it as following:

```
<% if (Model != null { %>
    <table>
       <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
           // Do stuff here with your item
       <% } %> 
    </table>
<% } %>
```

This way it doesn't look quite so out of the ordinary.